# PHP. Как из таблицы в бд взять поле

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Как из MySQL взять строки, и каждую строку поместить в отдельную переменную? 
P.S. Могу тупить, не очень разбираюсь.

Comment: Ну так это азы, нужно читать мануал в кратце `SELECT 'название столбца' или * FROM 'название таблицы'`. Пример `SELECT id FROM user`

Comment: Я это знаю, но как поместить отдельные строки из базы данных в php, чтобы он вывел значения этих строк.

Comment: И строка строка одна и та же, значения разные.